# Back button eventlistener Issue in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

In Phonegap 2.9.0 I have used the following code for some navigate purpose.

```
function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }
    function onBackKeyDown() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("Source") == 1) {
            window.history.go(-2);
        }
        else {
            window.history.go(-1);
        }
    }
    <body onload="onLoad()">
```

I have lot of pages in the App,

When i am using this code in one page,other pages back button not working.

when i use this code in all pages its working

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}
function onBackKeyDown() {
     window.history.go(-1);
    }
}
    <body onload="onLoad()">
```

Wheather this code unneccessary,please give any solution